# Could I have enough chain retention on a 1X system with just a narrow wide chainring without a clutch?

Tags: drivetrain

My bike is a 2017 Fuel EX 5, i am considering converting it to a 1X (pronounced '1 by') chainring. But i am unsure if i will get enough chain retention to stop my chain falling off with just a narrow wide chainring. Has anybody else tried this?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I am referring to trail riding

Comment: You are going to pull a Deore off a new bike?  You will still have 10 speed in the back.  Don't.

Comment: why not?? @Paparazzi

Comment: More money for less gearing and no clutch.

Comment: New mechs are expensive @Paparazzi

Comment: I am confused why a 2017 Deore has no clutch, is it broken?   Should 'work' (by 'work' I don't mean it will be as reliable as your 2x, - you will tell yourself it works, but if you had bought it from the shop you would be taking it back tell them it was no working), what sized cassette are you planning on?

Comment: Whatever you do, keep the old parts.  Bag them and store them for the future.

Comment: Im planning on a 11-36 with a 32t chainring @mattnz

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the terrain you are riding. If you have lots of rocks on your trails, like in Mediterranean countries your chain will fall here and there. On the other hand, if your riding terrain similar to nice flowing Alps singletracks, having narrow-wide chainring will probably be enough.
Also consider installing a chain guide, it costs about 10$, weights little and can save your chain from falling quite a lot. And don't forget a beefy chainstay guard, otherwise the sound of chain hitting alloy can drive you mad :-)

Answer (score 1):

Works fine. Not as secure as a clutch, but secure enough to not be a pain.

With a plain ring, I'd drop the chain at least once a lap of XC racing. Narrow-wide made it a once in every few weeks, and I don't think I've ever dropped a chain with a cutch.

Comment: I would call dropping a chain every couple of weeks 'not working'.

Comment: Depends on the riding you're doing. And maybe the change from terrible to just slightly inconvenient has me looking through rose tinted glasses. On grass or pavement it was never an issue though.